# how to access data in a angularjs promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to access a return promise data, but it always give me `undefined` even when i'm accessing to the correct element.

here is why i have to do it that way .

**controller.js**

```
 // can't access the data "tastes" in success outside from the .success call 
 // so i return the entire http call and access it later 
function loadContacts() {
      var contacts;
      return Account.getTastes()
              .success(function(tastes) {
              contacts= tastes[0].tastes;
              return contacts.map(function (c, index) {
                var colors = ["1abc9c", "16a085", "f1c40f", "f39c12", "2ecc71", "27ae60", "e67e22","d35400","3498db","2980b9","e74c3c","c0392b","9b59b6","8e44ad","34495e","2c3e50"];
                var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                var cParts = c.split(' ');
                var contact = {
                  name: c,
                  image: "http://dummyimage.com/50x50/"+color+"/f7f7f7.png&text="+c.charAt(0)
                };
                contact._lowername = contact.name.toLowerCase();
                return contact;
              });
              })
              .error(function(error) {
                console.log("Error:"+error)
              });

    }


/**
 * Search for contacts.
 */
function querySearch (query) {
  var results = query ?
      $scope.allContacts.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : [];
  return results;
}
/**
 * Create filter function for a query string
 */
function createFilterFor(query) {
  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
  return function filterFn(contact) {
    return (contact._lowername.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) != -1);;
  };
}

$scope.allContacts = loadContacts(); 
 console.log($scope.allContacts)
$scope.tags = [$scope.allContacts[0],$scope.allContacts[1]];
 // since $scope.allContacts is undefined thus, 
 //i'm having error for trying to access element[0] of undefined
```

the console.log($scope.allContacts) result is 
[image]

but when i try to access it like `$scope.allContacts.$$state.value.data` i get `undefined` as return. may i know what is the solution for this ?

**in my html**

```
<md-contact-chips required ng-model="tags" md-contacts="querySearch($query)" md-contact-name="name" md-contact-image="image"  filter-selected="true" placeholder="Thai, chinese, cheap, cafe and etc">
 </md-contact-chips>
```

**UPDATE: 1(SOLVED)**

i'm getting this error after i change my code to

```
 $scope.allContacts.then(function(contacts){
      $scope.tags = [contacts[0],contacts[1]];
  })

Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: $chip in $mdChipsCtrl.items, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined
```

i'm not even using ng-repeat why am i still getting ng-repeat error ?

**UPDATE: 2**
[image]
the chips is now being displayed however i can't search, when i try to search on the md-contact-chips this happened 
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using angular's $resource?

Comment: @XelharK sorry i'm kinda new to angularjs, may i know how can $resource resolve this problem ? thanks

Comment: Oh sure!

Basically, $resource is an object that helps you build resources to manage remote API calls (which is what you're doing here). The usage is extremely simple, and by the looks of it, it seemed to me that you were somehow trying to implement it on your own, so maybe there was something wrong in the angular implementation. 

Check here the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: @XelharK do you know any solution other than using $resource ?

Comment: I'll put it in the answer for easier reading

Comment: You need to bind querySearch to $scope... e.g $scope.querySearch = querySearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access contacts like so...

```
$scope.allContacts.then(function(contacts){
  console.log(contacts[0]);
  console.log(contacts[1]);
})
```

if you change

```
Account.getTastes().success
```

to

```
Account.getTastes().then
```

final results

```
function loadContacts() {
      var contacts;
      return Account.getTastes()
              .then(function(res) {
              contacts = res.data[0].tastes;
              return contacts.map(function (c, index) {
                var colors = ["1abc9c", "16a085", "f1c40f", "f39c12", "2ecc71", "27ae60", "e67e22","d35400","3498db","2980b9","e74c3c","c0392b","9b59b6","8e44ad","34495e","2c3e50"];
                var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                var cParts = c.split(' ');
                var contact = {
                  name: c,
                  image: "http://dummyimage.com/50x50/"+color+"/f7f7f7.png&text="+c.charAt(0)
                };
                contact._lowername = contact.name.toLowerCase();
                return contact;
              });
              })
              .error(function(error) {
                console.log("Error:"+error)
              });

    }

$scope.allContacts = loadContacts(); 
 console.log($scope.allContacts)
 $scope.allContacts.then(function(contacts){
   console.log(contacts[0]);
   console.log(contacts[1]);
 })
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply however i'm getting this as error `Account.getTastes(...).then(...).error is not a function`, may i know why ?

Comment: checkout 'Tracking and Duplicates' - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: i have updated my question, your solution is working however it affects other functions. but thanks for your help ! i really appreciate it

Comment: Why $scope.tags = [contacts[0],contacts[1]]? surely this should be $scope.tags = contacts? If either contacts[0] or contacts[1] are undefined you might get this error

Comment: $scope.tags = [contacts[0],contacts[1]] is insert tags , like you see in the screenshot above, if i put $scope.tags = contacts it will display all the tags in the md-contact-chips

Comment: Also... if i've answered your original question, could you accept my answer? Would be a good idea to close this question and open a new one if your question has changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82296/discussion-between-timsmiths-and-john-lim).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here seems to be that when you try to access the value, the promise is not resolved yet, so I guess it should be enough to wrap

```
$scope.tags = [$scope.allContacts[0],$scope.allContacts[1]];
```

into something like

```
$scope.allContacts.then(function(){
    $scope.tags = [$scope.allContacts[0],$scope.allContacts[1]];
}
```

Comment: i'm getting this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` as error. may i know why $scope.allContacts.$promise instead of $scope.allContacts.$$state ? because i don't see any $promise in $scope.allContacts when i console.log() it

Comment: Oh usually the angular resources have a $promise property that contains the promise. Just remove the $promise (see updated code)

Comment: i'm getting this error `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: $chip in $mdChipsCtrl.items, Duplicate key: undefined:undefined, Duplicate value: undefined `

Comment: That happens because you used the items in an ng-repeat, and it seems like there are several undefined keys in your array.

Try debugging it and see what these undefined keys are, this problem comes from a completely different source however.